# How to insert value to position a string instead %?

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to insert the values of variables to string instead of symbols %

```
<?
    function SpacerBlocks($number_space, $parent, $children, $array, $inside, $position_start = 0) {

        $result = '';
        $items = $result;
        for ($position_start; $position_start < count($array); $position_start++) { 
            $items.='<'.$children.'>' . 
                    printf($inside, $array[$position_start]['CNT'], 
                           $array[$position_start]['NAME']) . '</'.$children.'>';
            if ($position_start%$number_space == 0) {
                $result.='<'.$parent.'>'.$items.'</'.$parent.'>';
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

And call this function:

```
<?=SpacerBlocks(10, 'ul class="list"', 'li', $categories_doctors, 
                '<a href=""><span>%</span>%</a>');?>
```

But my construction does not work correct:

```
printf($inside, $array[$position_start]['CNT'], $array[$position_start]['NAME'])
```

Output is:

```
<a href=""><span>/span&gt;/a&gt;<ul class="list"><li>26</li></ul>           </span></a>
```

Comment: "does not work correct" becaaaause...? You get errors? output is not what you want?

Comment: Output is:   <a href=""><span>/span&gt;/a&gt;<ul class="list"><li>26</li></ul>   </span></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `%` are incorrect. It needs to be a proper format specifier, e.g.

```
printf('Hello %s PHP', 'from')
               ^--string format
```

will give you `Hello from PHP`.

Your printf string should be:

```
SpacerBlocks(....., '<a href=""><span>%s</span>%s</a>');
                                      ^^       ^^---note the S's
```

Also note that `printf()` does immediate output. You may want to use `sprintf()`, which returns the formated string instead of outputting it.

Comment: Thank you! you told me what I needed to! :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
str_replace('%',$replaceForThis,$input);
```